# How to save a .csv file in C drive (MQL4)

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I try to change the path of saving **`.csv`** file to C drive (the main dir).

Here the current code:

```
y="\"";
yy="\\"; 
Patch = "Csv_Files"+x2+Symbol()+x2;
```

I want the file that created to be rather saved in C drive ( the main dir ) instead in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\*********************\MQL4` dir.

How I can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Short version

In pure-**`MQL4`** no one can. `MQL4` a-priori sand-boxes all `fileIO` to take place just in subdirectories of **`Terminal/MQL4/Files`**, resp. **`Tester/Files`** ( in case of testing a code inside a Strategy Tester ).

### Still how to do that?

For security reasons, working with files is strictly controlled in the `MQL4` language. Files with which file operations are conducted using `MQL4` means, cannot be outside the file sandbox.

If `FILE_COMMON` is specified among flags, the file is opened in a shared folder for all MetaTrader 4 client terminals ( another magic ).

Nevertheless, you can setup distributed processing and orchestrate fileIO operations to be performed externally, via an unrestricted process and setup a peer-to-peer messaging or other DLL-based heterogenous distributed programming solution to escape from the box and write files wherever you need, even on a completely opposite side of the Earth ( remote logs et al ).